# Injecting bean declared in xml file using the @Inject annotation

Tags: spring, cdi

I can't get `@Inject` to work properly. I'm trying to inject a bean from xml using the `@Inject` annotation, but I get the error message
`"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required"`.

I have also been trying in combination with `@Qualifier("dataSource")`, but wherever I put the `@Qualifier` it says `"The annotation @Qualifier is disallowed for this location"`.

I have been reading loads of documentation on `@Inject` and I can't seem to find anything that mentions any special treatment of beans declared in xml.

However, I'm guessing Spring is trying to create the FooDaoImpl bean before scanning the dataSourceBean.

**How would I go about using `@Inject` to inject the dataSource bean declared in the xml file?
Is it even possible, using `@Inject`?**

FooDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class FooDaoImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements FooDao {

@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;

DSLContext create = DSL.using(dataSource, SQLDialect.DB2);

}
```

Spring-Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.foobar" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/BLABLA" />
    <property name="user" value="PAPAYA" />
    <property name="password" value="COCONUT" />
</bean>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Try adding `@Component` as an annotation to the class?

Comment: @Ben I think `@Repository` is a `@Component`. Also I have tried this, but it did not work, I'm afraid. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use `@Inject` to inject the dataSource to my Dao. I used a `@PostConstruct` to achieve this, like so:

```
@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;

@PostConstruct
private void initialize(){
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}

DSLContext create = DSL.using(dataSource, SQLDialect.DB2);
```

I'm sure there is a better, or "cleaner" way of achieving this, but none that I could find.
Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in Spring.  I use the `@Autowired` annotation, not `@Inject`.

Comment: I would preferably get this to work with `@Inject`, as I'm using this throughout the rest of the application for DI. However, I tried `@Autowired` using `autowire="byType"`, but no cigar. I'll try to get it working though. (Also, will that be considered a good practice, given I'm using a third party class as datasource?)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the **The annotation @Qualifier is disallowed for this location** message you have to use the annotation `@interface`.